# Getting Unity AR Objects to the Front - Ability to change the render pipeline for the game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, render, augmented-reality

I am trying to display the game objects or prefabs generated by Unity overlaying all textures.

In detail: At the moment I have created an AR application for smartphones and inserted a `RawImage` into it:

[image: Screenshot_Unity]

A script `CPU_RawImage.cs` takes the live image from the camera and transfers it to this `RawImage`:

[image: Screenshot_Smartphone]

As you can see on the screenshot, it is unfortunately not possible to transfer the created virtual objects (in this case the house) to the `RawImage`.

Therefore my question is there a possibility to change this render order for the created objects, or any other possibility to make these objects visible ?

I have been trying to find a setting for the Render Order, so far I have not been able to locate such an option for 3D Application. I was also advised to try Render / Graphic - Pipline or Shaders, but I have no experience.

**Edit 01**
*Solution with 2 Cameras and a RenderTexture*

I followed the instructions from below. I created a second camera as a child of the AR camera and rendered Target Textzure to a RenderTexture.

In the UI I created a second RawImage and applied the RenderTexture to it. [Unity_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9FhE.jpg)

The result on the smartphone display looks like this:
[Screenshot_Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA0Pj.jpg)

As you can see, the VR object is on top of the RawImage, but somehow pixelated and with an offset when you compare the top and bottom half. Any suggestions for the problem ?

Comment: I am a bit confused .. isn't the upper half of the screen basically doing exactly what you are trying to achieve using the `RawImage` ..? In general: A `Screenspace  Overlay` Canvas is called like that as it will always overlay .. it is one of the last things rendered on top after everything else in your scene has already finished rendering

Comment: Right the top half does exactly what it should, but im trying to get the virtual object above this RawImage. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably have to render the model with a second camera to a rendertexture then. And show that rendertexture in a rawImage in the UI

Comment: @pixlhero Ok, that sounds like a plan, but I honestly don't understand what exactly you mean by that. Use a second AR camera and in this do the AR algorithmimc and insert to the RawImage ?

Comment: What I mean is: What do you need the RawImage for in the first place? The upper half already is rendered exactly like what you want to achieve so why not stick to that then?

Comment: @derHugo I try to find some "real" objects in this texture and filter them out. Hence this green Recatangel, which turns part of the RawImage transparent and slightly green.

Comment: as I understood it: you want to display ONLY the virtual objects in front of the UI?

Comment: @pixlhero correct only the virtual objects

Answer (score 0):

Add a standard Unity Camera as a child of your AR Camera. This should make it such that these two cameras have the same view (except the Camera Background. Also set the camera clear flag such that the background will be transparent. Then set the render target of that new camera to a RenderTexture. (There should be a lot of guides online how to do that). Then display that render Texture in your UI as you see fit.

Because the second camera only sees the virtual objects, the RenderTexture will also only contain those. If something looks skewed, check if the FOV of the two cameras match during runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps me a lot for now! How can I check the FOV of the two cameras? - I suspect I have a problem with this, will post the results below.

Comment: Seeing from your screenshots you will have to adapt the resolution of the rendertexture to the resolution of the screen. There's a lot of examples out there in the web on how to do this. [fov](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html) can be compared and set accordingly on the second camera through a script.